# how to get angular form input value using django api?

Tags: django, angular, api

Here is the Angular Login Form which sends data to the `get(formData.value)`

```
 <form class="form-horizontal" [formGroup]="formData" (ngSubmit)="get(formData.value)">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <div class="form-group row">
                        <label for="inputEmail3" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Email</label>
                        <div class="col-sm-10">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputEmail3" placeholder="Email" 
                            formControlName="user">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group row">
                        <label for="inputPassword3" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Password</label>
                        <div class="col-sm-10">
                            <input type="password" class="form-control" id="inputPassword3" 
                            placeholder="Password" 
                            formControlName="pwd">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group row">
                        <div class="offset-sm-2 col-sm-10">
                            <div class="form-check">
                                <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" id="exampleCheck2">
                                <label class="form-check-label" for="exampleCheck2">Remember me</label>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="card-footer">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info">Sign in</button>
                    <but

ton type="submit" class="btn btn-default float-right">Cancel</button>
                </div>

            </form>
```

Here is the `.ts file`

```
get(formData : any) {  
    this.userData.userLogin(formData).subscribe((response) => {
    console.log(response);
    },
    error => {
      console.log(JSON.stringify(error.json()));
    })
```

Here is the Angular `service.ts` file method

```
   userLogin(data: any){
    return this.http.post(this.loginUrl, data, {responseType: 'text'} ) 
   }
```

Here is the Django Login API Code

```
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt
@csrf_exempt
def login(request):
    try:
        response_data = {}
        if request.method == 'POST':
            return HttpResponse(request)  // {"user":"Umair","pwd":"12345"}(by returning the request it shows angular form input values)

            user = request.POST['user']
            pwd = request.POST['pwd']
            Emp = Employee.objects.filter(Emp_Name=user, Emp_Pwd=pwd).exists()
            if Emp is True:
                if 'UserName' not in request.session:
                    request.session['UserName'] = user
                response_data['response'] = "LOGIN SUCCESS!"
                response_data['IsLogin'] = "TRUE"
                return HttpResponse(json.dumps(response_data), content_type="application/json")
                return HttpResponseRedirect('Dashboard')
            else:
                response_data['response'] = "Invalid UserName Or Password!"
                response_data['IsLogin'] = "FALSE"
                return HttpResponse(json.dumps(response_data), content_type="application/json")
        else:
            response_data['response'] = "Request Method must be POST rather than GET"
            response_data['REQUIRED METHOD'] = "POST"
            return HttpResponse(json.dumps(response_data), content_type="application/json")
    except Exception as e:
        return HttpResponse("Error !" + str(e))
```

As you can see in the image given below The `API` returns angular form input values

how to get the POST form values and saved in these variables given below:

```
            user = request.POST['user']
            pwd = request.POST['pwd']
```

Here is the attached screenshot

[image]

Any Help would be appreciated and thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally i figured out the solution how to `save form values` into the `variables` that is coming from `angular` reactive forms using the `django Login API`

Here is the code

```
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt
from rest_framework.parsers import JSONParser
import requests
@csrf_exempt
def login(request):
    try:
        response_data = {}
       
        response = JSONParser().parse(request)
         //response = {user: 'Umair', pwd: '123'} // angular form values
        if request.method == 'POST':
            user = response['user']
            pwd = response['pwd']
            Emp = Employee.objects.filter(Emp_Name=user, Emp_Pwd=pwd).exists()
            if Emp is True:
                response_data['response'] = "LOGIN SUCCESS!"
                response_data['IsLogin'] = "TRUE"

                return HttpResponse(json.dumps(response_data), content_type="application/json")
            else:
                response_data['response'] = "Invalid UserName Or Password!"
                response_data['IsLogin'] = "FALSE"
                return HttpResponse(json.dumps(response_data), content_type="application/json")
           

    except Exception as e:
        return HttpResponse("Error !" + str(e))
```